# Find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this BVP: transforming the eqn?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so I've been stuck on this problem after my first attempt. I got the trivial solution after using the characteristic equation $3r^2 - 4r + 1 = 0$...

Find all eigenvalues and associated eigenfunctions for the BVP $$3f''(x) + 4f'(x) + \nu f(x) = 0$$ where $$f'(7) = 1 = f'(8)$$ I've exhausted Google and my book as my resource because it doesn't explain how to do it. But the closest I got to help is here, http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~shimaby/math322_BVP2.pdf example 7. However the hint says use $y = xu(x)$, but how do I know what '$y$' to use? Reduction of order will make it into a first-order ode which is not what I want, all of the problems I've looked at are of the form $\phi''(x) = \pm\lambda\phi(x)$.

I just want to know how to get started, such as transforming the above second order ode into one of the form $f''(x) = \pm\lambda f(x)$. I do not need a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a function $g$ such that $f(x) = g(x)e^{ax}$.

Then

$$f'(x) = ae^{ax}g(x) + e^{ax}g'(x),\\
f''(x) = a^2e^{ax}g(x) + 2ae^{ax}g'(x)+e^{ax}g''(x),$$

and

$$0=3f''(x) + 4f'(x) +\nu f(x) = e^{ax}[3g''(x)+(6a+4)g'(x) + (3a^2+4a+\nu)g(x)]$$

Choose $a = -\frac{2}{3}$ to eliminate the first-derivative in the differential equation for $g$.  Then $f(x) = g(x)e^{-2x/3}$ with

$$3g''(x) +(\nu-\frac{4}{3})g(x)=0.$$

Now solve the BVP for $g$.

Comment: What was your thinking process for this?

Comment: @Don Larynx:  I added some steps.  I knew I could eliminate the first derivative by choosing $a = -2/3$ with$f(x)= \exp(ax)g(x)$.  This is a general technique that can work even if the coeeficients are not constants, but it is very simple in this case.

Comment: -- and the exponential factor is never zero and can be divided out.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I ended up getting the general sol for g. Now do I just take the derivative of f = g(exp) and plug in boundary conditions?

Comment: Yes. For example $g'(7)-(2/3)g(7)= exp(14/3)$